# Linq Update Query with Multiple Tables

Tags: sql, linq

I am confused how to convert the following query in Linq.

```
UPDATE TABLETEMP 
SET FLD1= A.SCODE,FLD2=B.STATUS 
FROM TABLETIME A,TABLETIME1 B,TABLETEMP C 
WHERE A.COM=B.COM 
AND A.SCODE=B.SCODE 
AND A.CODE=C.CODE 
AND A.SDATE=C.TDATE1
```

Anyone having any idea How to do this with all the conditions?

Comment: Is TABLETEMP, TABLETIME, TABLETIME1, TABLETIME3 physically exists or any one of them temp table?

Comment: These tables exists in database. I edited the last table name as a correction.

Comment: Can you show how you defined your models in Linq? Are you using Entity Framework, Linq to SQL, something else?

Comment: It must be noted that you cannot convert update query directly to linq in most cases (EF for example), because you have to first read object you want to update into memory, then update it and save changes, which results in 2 (useless) database calls. If you are using EF, you may try to use https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended to overcome this.

Answer (score 1):

```
var tble =   (from A in datacontext.TABLETIMEs
              from B in datacontext.TABLETIME1
              from C in datacontext.TABLETIME3 
              from D in datacontext.TABLETEMP
               where A.COM=B.COM &&
               A.CODE=C.CODE &&
               A.SDATE=C.TDATE1
               select new {A, B, C, D}).FirstOrDefault();

   if(tble !=null )
  {
    tble.FLD1=tble.SCODE;
    tble.FLD2=tble.STATUS;
    datacontext.Submitchanges();
  }
```